# Parsing string based on initial format

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a set of lines and extract certain parts of the string based on an initial format (reading a configuration file).

A little more explanation: the format can contain up to *4* parts to be formatted. This case, `%S` will skip the part, `%a-%c` will extract  the part and will be treated as a string, `%d` as int.

What I am trying to do now is to come up with some clever way to parse it. So far I came up with the following prototype. However, my pointer arithmetic still needs some work to skip/extract the parts.

Ultimately each part will be stored on an array of structs.

**Edit:** using `sscanf` might not work in this case, since the format is specified in a configuration file. Additionally, the format could scale, string (and type) may change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

void process (const char *fmt, const char *line) {
   char c;
   const char *src = fmt;
   while ((c = *src++) != '\0')
   {   
      if (c == 'S');      // skip part
      else if (c == 'a'); // extract %a
      else if (c == 'b'); // extract %b
      else if (c == 'c'); // extract %c
      else if (c == 'd'); // extract %d (int)
      else { 
         printf("Unknown format\n");
         exit(1);
      }   
   }
}

static const char *input[] = {
   "bar 200.1 / / (zaz) - \"bon 10\"",
   "foo 100.1 / / (baz) - \"apt 20\"",
};

int main (void) {
   const char *fmt = "%S %a / / (%b) - \"%c %d\"";
   size_t i;
   for(i = 0; i < DIM (input); i++) 
   {
      process (fmt, input[i]);
   }   
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Appears you want to create a new printf, Am I right? Give us a example of input and what should be the output.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Something like printf? Because this won't work....

Comment: I'm not trying to re-create another printf, all I want is to extract the parts based on the specified format.

Comment: I think he's trying to implement a custom [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

Comment: I forgot to mention, the format will be specified by the user in a configuration file. So, I'm not sure if using sscanf will help.

Answer (score 1):

scanf expressions are sometimes sufficiently powerful to parse actual input, and it's possible to build them at runtime or compile time. So, i'd try to follow that path before reinventing the wheel:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

static const char *input[] = {
   "bar 200.1 / / (zaz) - \"bon 10\"",
   "foo 100.1 / / (baz) - \"apt 20\"",
};
const char *format = "%*[^ ] %[^ ] / / (%[^)]) - \" %[^ ] %d \"";

int main()
{
 typedef char buffer[100];
 buffer A,B,C;
 int D, i, p;

 for (i = 0; i < DIM(input); i++) {
  if ((p = sscanf(input[i], format, A, B, C, &D)) == 4)
   printf("%s %s %s %d\n", A, B, C, D);
  else
   printf("parsed only %d\n", p);
 }
}
```

produces:

```
200.1 zaz bon 10
100.1 baz apt 20
```

Comment: chac: since the user specifies the format on a conf file, I'm wondering if sscanf would understand the format posted on the question?

Comment: Kayla: I see no problem to get the specification from a file, use fgets(). As i suggested, specifications (that *are* a subset of regexp) can be as well composed runtime, via strcat.

Answer (score 0):

parsing according to a format can be difficult without strict definitions of each placeholder.
how do you plan on handling cases like:

```
fmt = "(%c)";

input = "(a)bc)";
```

?

clearly, the user wanted to get "a)bc", but since ')' was your end-parse token you only got "a"

Comment: If was that, I think regex is the easier and fast solution. Searching for and replace then.

Comment: extracting `a` will be fine for now, later, on a different function I could verify if what it was extracted matches to what is supposed to be.